# How do i disable JScrollPane borders?

Tags: java, swing, border, jscrollpane

I'm trying to make the JScrollPane transperant, So what i did was:

```
    scrollPane_1.setViewportBorder(null);
    scrollPane_1.setOpaque(false);
    scrollPane_1.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    scrollPane_1.setBorder(null);
    scrollPane_1.getViewport().setBorder(null);
```

So now, the JScrollPane is transparent, But the border still shows, and all my attempts to remove it as failed, How do i remove the border?

-thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [JScrollPane Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy%28int%29)

This should work:

```
scrollPane_1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollPane_1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but it's still not working EDIT: It is working , my bad, Thankyou !